# Using a variable created in list comprehension

Tags: python, variables, list-comprehension

I want to use the variable "i" created in `poss = [j.split() for j in [decipher(i, txt) for i in range(1, 26)]]`, but it raises a NameError when I try to access it in line `return f"The key is {i} and the deciphered text is{' '.join(k)}."`. Is there any way to do this without raising an error?

```
popular = open("C:/Users/NAME/FilesForPyCharm/popular.txt")
words = [line.strip() for line in popular]
poss = [j.split() for j in [decipher(i, txt) for i in range(1, 26)]]
for k in poss:
    if set(k).issubset(set(words)):
        return f"The key is {i} and the deciphered text is{' '.join(k)}."
```

Comment: i is only defined in list comprehension. You can put 25 directly as this is the end value, so it's probably not the proper way to go, the loop doesn't short-circuit

Comment: `poss = [(i, decipher(i, txt).split()) for i in range(1, 26)]` and then `for i,k in poss:...`

Comment: The i gets assigned all the values from 1 to 25, which of these should be used and when in your print string?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: I had a look at the duplicate target question that you mentioned, and there doesn't seem to be any duplication at alll. Of course, I did not read every answer to that question to see if any of those answers coincidentally happened to have answer for this one too.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the value of `i` with its corresponding element and then loop over the pairs:

```
popular = open("C:/Users/NAME/FilesForPyCharm/popular.txt")
words = [line.strip() for line in popular]
poss = [(j.split(), i) for j in [decipher(i, txt) for i in range(1, 26)]]
for k, i in poss:
    if set(k).issubset(set(words)):
        return f"The key is {i} and the deciphered text is{' '.join(k)}."
```